# Implicit function theorem for matrices

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

```
I have a homework assignment for the question below and
I honestly don't even know where to start. 
Any hints or solutions would be very helpful. 
Thanks!
```

Question:

Let $M$ denote the set of complex $n \times n$ - matrices endowed with the operator norm.

For $A$, $B$ and $C$ in $M$, consider the equation:

$ABCA + CABC = BCAB + I$

Use the implicit function theorem to prove that there exists a smooth function $F$, defined in some neighborhood of $(I,I)$ such that,

$F(I,I)= \mathbf{I}$  and 
such that $C = F(A,B)$ 
satisfies the above equation for $A$ and $B$ close enough to $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have it all set up: Consider the function
$$f\colon M\times M\times M \to M, \quad f(A,B,C) = ABCA+CABC-BCAB.$$
We need to see that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial C}(I,I,I)$ gives an invertible map $M\to M$. As a hint, consider $f(I,I,I+tC')=(I+tC')^2$.

**EDIT**: Then we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}(I,I,I)(0,0,C') = 2C',$$
so $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial C}(I,I,I)$ is an invertible linear map from $M$ to $M$.

Comment: BTW, note that Ted's $f$ is different from the $F$ you're supposed to produce. If I were Ted, I might have written $$f: (M \times M) \times M \to M : ( (A, B), C) \mapsto ABCA + CABC-BCAB$$, but that's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I'm trying to figure out how to use $\frac^{\partial f}_{\partial C} (I,I,I + tC')$ to show that $F(A,B)=C$ when $A$ and $B$ is close enough to $I$. What is the relation between $F$ and $f$?

Comment: You need to understand the statement of the implicit function theorem! A level set of a smooth function (in our case $f$) can be expressed locally as a graph (in our case $C=F(A,B)$) provided the appropriate part of the derivative matrix has maximal rank.

Comment: The IFT states that there exists a function $F$ such that $f(A,B,F(A,B)) = f(A,B,C)$, if the "C-derivative" och $f$ is invertible. And to show that it is invertible, I need to consider your hint. Did I get it right?

Comment: Only on a level set $f(A,B,C) = \text{constant}$, @karamell.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the idea. Now I use the inverse function theorem to show that $\frac^{\partial f}_{\partial C} (I,I,I + tC')$ is invertible?

Comment: No, no inverse function theorem. You're going to understand the "partial derivative" $\partial f/\partial C$ by finding its value, as a linear map, on the matrix $C'$ by computing the directional derivative with the limit definition.

Comment: Thanks again. This is unknown territory for me and this is as far as I got: $\partial f / \partial C = lim_{h \to 0} (f(I,I,I + tC') - f(I,I,I)) / t|C'|$. Is it anywhere near correct?